# OpenRecordset on a Linked Table?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I split off a few large tables from my AccessDB to a backend database without issue.

Next, I need to open a recordset to replace various troublesome characters.  The following snippet worked fine when the table was local, but Access complains now that the table is LINKED, but provides no detail.

```vb
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset

'Step thru the Item table fix ' & " characters
Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("Item", dbOpenTable)
Do While Not rs3.EOF
    strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs3!DESC), Chr(39), Chr(39) & Chr(39))
    strDesc = Replace(Nz(rs3!DESC), Chr(34), "")
    rs3.MoveNext
Loop
Set rs3 = Nothing
```

Any suggestions for accomplishing this task with a LINKED table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dbOpenTable` can only be used with a local table; it can not be used with a linked table.

```vb
'Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("Item", dbOpenTable)
Set rs3 = db.OpenRecordset("Item")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'I allways use this format scheme, and it works perfectly, with local or 
'linked tables (In fact, I always use linked tables...):

Dim bd As Database
Dim reg As Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set bd = CurrentDb
    Set reg = bd.OpenRecordset("Select * from Pacientes", dbOpenDynaset)
end sub

' for a new record
reg.AddNew

' for updates
reg.Update

' for delete
reg.Delete

' to fill a table record
reg("Dni") = txtDni

' to read a table record
txtDni = reg("Dni")

' txtDni is the field's name in the form
' Dni is the field's name in the table

' to find a record
 Dim Finder As String
 Finder = InputBox("Dni: ")
 If Finder <> "" Then
    reg.FindFirst "Dni=" & Trim(Finder)

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    reg.Close
    bd.Close
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28400065)